# custom radio button background color is not working on internet explorer

Tags: html, css

I Have Custom radio buttons like :

```
https://screenshots.firefox.com/SIa4ExZ50mcwP2Wd/localhost
```

through this code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    .seco {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;

        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;

        border: 2px solid #999;
        transition: 0.2s all linear;
        outline: none;
        margin-right: 5px;

        position: relative;
        top: 4px;
    }

    .seco:checked {
        border: 3px solid black;
        background: #1df01d;
    }

    .faso {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;

        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;

        border: 2px solid #999;
        transition: 0.2s all linear;
        outline: none;
        margin-right: 5px;

        position: relative;
        top: 4px;
    }

    .faso:checked {
        border: 3px solid black;
        background: red;
    }
</style>
<body>

      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 " >
      <div class="col-md-10" >
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-padding" >
      <p class="skill_eng"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-padding"  >
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 no-padding"  >
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 "  >
      <input type="radio" checked="checked" class="faso" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 skill_radio" >
      <input type="radio" class="seco">
      </div> 
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-padding" >
      <p ></p>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

But in my case its working fine with the mozila,chrome and safari but
 its not working with internet explorer. why this happening i am not
 able to understand is there any easy way to run this code with the
internet explorer (ie). please help me related this from tommorrow i
stuck with this ....'

in internet explorer its now showing the color on background but working fine with the chrome and mozila..

Answer (score 1):

The secret is that in Internet Explorer, the `:checked` styles the **outside** of the `<input>`, which you don't see. In order to change the check itself, you're looking for the `::ms-check` pseudo-class, applying the following rules to specifically target Internet Explorer:

```
.engyes:checked::-ms-check {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: #1df01d;
}

.engno:checked::-ms-check {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: red;
}
```

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.engyes {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  transition: 0.2s all linear;
  outline: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

.engyes:checked {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: #1df01d;
}

.engno {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  transition: 0.2s all linear;
  outline: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

.engno:checked {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: red;
}

.engyes:checked::-ms-check {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: #1df01d;
}

.engno:checked::-ms-check {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 no-padding skill-main">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12 no-padding skill-inside">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-padding">
        <p class="skill_eng" style="text-align:center;"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-padding">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 no-padding skill_radio">
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" id="engno'+val.id+'" name="eradios['+val.id+']" value="0" data-for="no" class="radio-design engno">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 skill_radio">
            <input type="radio" id="engyes'+val.id+'" name="eradios['+val.id+']" value="'+val.id+'" data-for="yes" class="radio-design engyes">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-padding">
        <p class="skill_arb" style="text-align:center;"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: its working fine but dot inside radio is showing in internet explorer.. how can i remove that dot from the radio ...

Comment: is there any solution for removing that dot in internet explore ??

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not cross-browser. Try following way, here note 2 important issue set `for` value your input `id` and label must immediate after corresponding `radio buttton`. Right now I keep them as a placeholder

```css
.manage-radio {
 position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
 z-index: -1;
}
.style-radio {
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 width:16px;
 height:16px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 background-color:#fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
.manage-radio:checked + .style-radio {
    border: 3px solid #000;
 background-color:#1df01d;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 ">
 <input type="radio" id="id1" class="radio-design engyes manage-radio">
    <label class="style-radio" for="id1"></label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 skill_radio">
 <input type="radio" id="id2" class="radio-design engyes manage-radio">
    <label class="style-radio" for="id2"></label>
</div>
```